# Reading the Latitude and longitude from Json and calculate driving directions

Tags: react-native

I am reading a json file to read the services provided in different cities. I am displaying the servics on a master page and when users click on the services, I redirect them to the page where the services are offered. I need to show them the driving directions to those services. Below is my services.Json file:

```
    [

{
    "id":1,
    "ser": "Test Service",
    "Location": "Orange County",
    "Phone":"(777)-922-5151",
    "SecondLoc": "Los Angeles",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "sourceLat":"-33.8356372",
    "sourceLong":"18.6947617",
    "destLat":"-33.8600024",
    "destLong":"18.697459"
  }
]
```

Below is the screen shot of my service on the phone:

[image]

when I tap on Test Service. I am redirected to another page that shows the longitude , latitude of the source and destination and the cities where the service is offered. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

Below is my code to show the directions to the users:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import getDirections from 'react-native-google-maps-directions'
const theme = getTheme();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },
  title1: {
      top: 10,
      left: 80,
      fontSize: 24,
  },
  title2: {
      top: 35,
      left: 82,
      fontSize: 18,
  },
  image: {
      flex: 0,
      height: 100,
      width: 333,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  closeIcon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 5,
      left: 295,
      color: 'rgba(233,166,154,0.8)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },  
  icon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 15,
      left: 0,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },
  textArea: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingTop: 10,
      width: 260,
  },
  textIcons: {
      color: '#26a69a',
  },
  actionArea: {
      paddingTop: 10,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },

  title:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 10,
    alignSelf:'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 19,
    },

    SerContent:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 15,
        paddingTop: 10,
        alignSelf:'center',
    },
    underLineText: {
        fontSize: 12,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        color: 'red',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
      }
});
class ServiceDetail extends Component {
    handleClick = (link) => {
        Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(link);
            } else {
                console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
            }
        });
    };

    handleGetDirections = () => {
        const data = {
           source: {
            latitude: -33.8356372,
            longitude: 18.6947617
          },
          destination: {
            latitude: -33.8600024,
            longitude: 18.697459
          },
          params: [
            {
              key: "travelmode",
              value: "driving"        // may be "walking", "bicycling" or "transit" as well
            },
            {
              key: "dir_action",
              value: "navigate"       // this instantly initializes navigation using the given travel mode 
            }
          ]
        }

        getDirections(data)
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={[theme.cardStyle, styles.card]}>

        <SimpleIcon name={'close'} size={30} style={styles.closeIcon}
            onPress={() => this.props.noneSelected()} />
        <Text  style={styles.title}>{this.props.services.ser}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.SerContent} >Service is available in the following locations:</Text>
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}> {this.props.services.Location} </Text>   
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}> {this.props.services.sourceLat} </Text> 
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}> {this.props.services.sourceLong} </Text> 
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}> {this.props.services.destLat} </Text> 
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}> {this.props.services.destLong} </Text> 
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleGetDirections}>
        <Text style={styles.underLineText}>directions</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.SerContent}>{this.props.services.SecondLoc}</Text>




        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        services: state.serviceSelected
     };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceDetail);
```

I am not sure how to put these Longitude and Latitude data in that const data variable so that I don't have to hard code the Longitude and latitude like I did in my code. I can see the driving directions with the existing code, but Longitude and latitude are hard coded. I am very new to React Native. Right now when I click on driving directions, I see the below screen shot:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand well your problem, if I didn't understand well please let me a comment.
So if you want to open navigation to a specific destination you can use this:

Android:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('google.navigation:q=55+57')}>
```

where `q` is the destination lat + long

IOS:

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('maps://app?saddr=50+55&daddr=55+57')}>
```

where `saddr` is start address and `daddr` is destination address lat+long

To use it from JSON you should concatenate your URLs:

```
destUrl = 'google.navigation:q=' yourJson.lat + '+' + yourJson.long
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(destUrl)}>
```

Comment: I know how to open a navigation. I just want to read the values of latitude and longitude from json file and instead of using hard coded values of latitude and longitude, I want to read them  from json file. In above  case, I am not using json to read the values

Comment: Updated the answer, please try that.

Comment: Thank You. I can open the map, but its is asking for starting address